# Why i don't have GuildMessageReceivedEvent?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm making discord bot and i need make a commands like "kick" but JDA has only MessageReceiveEvent. I checked in docs and its says in jda has GuildMessageReceiveEvent but code only says about MessageReceivedEvent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GuildMessageReceiveEvent has been removed and replaced by `MessageReceivedEvent` in JDA 5+. To only handle guild messages you just check `event.isFromGuild()` in your event:

```java
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
  if (!event.isFromGuild()) return;
  ...
}
```